# why flask auto debug not working in ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, flask

When I run

```
python app.py
```

where content of `app.py` is:

```
 from flask import Flask ,render_template

    from data import articles


    app=Flask(__name__)

    Articles=articles()

    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return render_template('home.html')


    @app.route('/about')
    def about():
        return render_template('about.html')

    @app.route('/articles')
    def articles():
        return render_template('articles.html',articles=Articles)


    @app.route('/article/<string:id>/')
    def article(id):
        return render_template('article.html',id=id)

    if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "app.py", line 32, in <module>

    app.run(debug=True)

restore_signals, start_new_session)

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in > _execute_child

  raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)

OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error:

/home/haseeb/Documents/Flask/flask_web/app.py
```

Comment: Start by fixing the indentation in your code.

Comment: I dont Understand

Comment: Indentation is the spacing before each line of code. In Python, incorrect indentation breaks the code logic.

Comment: Still Not working

Comment: Please show how you fixed the indentation in your post.

Comment: check It now ! i have correct Indentation

Comment: It's still incorrect. Check my answer.

Comment: @HaseebShinwari: Hi, I have fixed some things in your post including formatting of the code and the error log. On Stack Overflow there is a simple way for format them: select the whole code (or the error log), and press `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button. **Do not** format a code and a log as a *blockquote* - such formatting looses newlines, which helps a lot when understanding the code or the log.

Comment: thanks next time i will take care of this

Comment: Why i get negative voting still confuse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### best Sloution is to  use_reloader

```py
if __name__=='__main__':

    app.run(port=5000,debug=True,use_reloader=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

To enable debugging for Flask in Ubuntu you can do the following:
Set environment variables for Flask:

```
$ export FLASK_DEBUG=1
$ export app=app.py # change to whatever the filename is
```

Then run your Flask-app by typing:

```
$ run flask
```

From the [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#debug-mode)

Answer (score 0):

Indentation matters:

```
from flask import Flask ,render_template
from data import articles

app=Flask(__name__)

Articles=articles()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')

@app.route('/articles')
def articles():
    return render_template('articles.html',articles=Articles)

@app.route('/article/<string:id>/')
def article(id):
    return render_template('article.html',id=id)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: I Am using Ubuntu Operation System

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: On terminal before running flask, run the following commands:

```
$ export FLASK_DEBUG=1
$ export app=app.py
```

Then:

```
flask run
```